# Spring Mvc Returning raw Json in treeview

Tags: java, json, spring

treeController.java

```
@Controller
public class TreeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/mytree",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        return "tree";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getTechList", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public @ResponseBody List<FlatObject.Technology> getTechList(){
        FlatObject ensureCapacity = new FlatObject();
        List<FlatObject.Technology> techList = ensureCapacity.getTechList();
         return techList;


        } 

    }
```

modelclass which generates treenode

```
public class FlatObject {

    List<Technology> techList = new ArrayList<Technology>(1000);
    private boolean child;
    private Technology root;

    public List<Technology> getTechList() {
        if(techList.isEmpty()){      
            ((ArrayList<Technology>) techList).ensureCapacity(1000);
             techList.add(new Technology("Root",1,0));
            techList.add(new Technology("Node 1",2,1));
            techList.add(new Technology("Node 1.1",3,2));
            techList.add(new Technology("Node 1.2",4,2));

            techList.add(new Technology("Node 2",5,1));
            techList.add(new Technology("Node 2.1",6,5));
            techList.add(new Technology("Node 2.2",7,5));
            techList.add(new Technology("Node 2.3",8,5));
        }
        return techList;
    }


    public void setTechList(List<Technology> techList) {
        this.techList = techList;
    }

    public class Technology {

        private int id;
        private int Parentid ;
        private String techName;

        public int getid() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setid(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getParentid() {
            return Parentid;
        }

        public void setParentid(int Parentid) {
            this.Parentid = Parentid;
        }

        public String getTechName() {
            return techName;
        }

        public void setTechName(String techName) {
            this.techName = techName;
        }

        public Technology(String techName,int id, int Parentid) {
            this.id = id;
            this.Parentid = Parentid;
            this.techName = techName;
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
{
id: 1,
techName: "Root",
parentid: 0
},
{
id: 2,
techName: "Node 1",
parentid: 1
},
{
id: 3,
techName: "Node 1.1",
parentid: 2
},
{
id: 4,
techName: "Node 1.2",
parentid: 2
},
{
id: 5,
techName: "Node 2",
parentid: 1
},
{
id: 6,
techName: "Node 2.1",
parentid: 5
},
```

I am creating tree strucutre using java and springmvc and returning to view in json object .The json not in tree format.so
i want json format like nodes in different level, these all are in same level.how to do this ,please help

i want output like this:

```
{
data: "Node 3",
state: "open",
children: [
{
data: "Node 3.1",
attr: {
techname: "Node 3.1"
}
},
{
data: "Node 3.2",
attr: {
techname: "Node 3.2"
}
}
],
attr: {
techname: "Node 3"
}
},
{
data: "Node 4",
state: "open",
children: [
{
data: "Node 4.2",
attr: {
techname: "Node 4.2"
}
},
{
data: "Node 4.3",
attr: {
techname: "Node 4.3"
}
},
{
data: "Node 4.4",
attr: {
techname: "Node 4.4"
}
}
],
attr: {
techname: "Node 4"
}
},
```

I am using HashMap and list to Produce output like Json What i pasted but its not working,Please help how to achieve this, have to write code in spring controller side

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mytree", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        return "tree";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getTechList", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> getTTechList() {

        try {
              DataClass dataClass = new DataClass();
              List<DataClass.Technology> listCPV = dataClass.getTechList();

            Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            for (int i = 0; i < listCPV.size();) {
                Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map2.put("state", "open");
                map2.put("data", listCPV.get(i).getTechName());


                Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map3.put("techname", listCPV.get(i).getTechName());
                String jsonAttr = null;
                map2.put("attr", jsonAttr);
                map3 = null;

                if (listCPV.get(i + 1).getId() == 0) {
                    Map<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    while (listCPV.get(i + 1).getId() == 0) {
                        i++;
                        Map<String, String> map5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map5.put("data", listCPV.get(i).getTechName());

                        Map<String, String> map6 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map6.put("techname", listCPV.get(i).getTechName());
                        String jsonChildAttr = null;
                        map5.put("attr",jsonChildAttr);
                        map6 = null;

                        map4.putAll(map5);
                        map5 = null;

                        if (listCPV.size() == (i + 1)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                }
                i++;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
{
id: 1,
techName: "Root",
parentid: 0,
child: [{
        id: 2,
        techName: "Node 1",
        parentid: 1,
        child:[ {
            id: 3,
            techName: "Node 1.1",
            parentid: 2,
            child:
            },{
            id: 4,
            techName: "Node 1.2",
            parentid: 2,
            child:
            } ]
        },{
        id: 5,
        techName: "Node 2",
        parentid: 1,
        child: [{
            id: 6,
            techName: "Node 2.1",
            parentid: 5,
            child:
            }]
        }]
}
```

And if yes then there has to be changes to your java code. From from my exp it should be more a combination of a list and a map.
Kindly let me know if you still cant do it but do share your efforts applied to achieve the same.

Comment: ya exactly i want like this

Comment: great so now you now what exactly you need, any thoughts on what code changes should be done to achieve this or what logical changes you think should be applied here, Kindly let me know if you are stuck but do provide the efforts you have applied to achieve the solution

Comment: i am trying to achieve it using hashmap, and i pasted my code please take a look at it, but returning nothing

Comment: so now you need to understand the usage GSON library for that. Here is the sample code

`List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
foo.add("A");
foo.add("B");
foo.add("C");
String json = new Gson().toJson(foo );`

Kindly let me know if you can make it work else I will help you

Comment: Kindly let me know if the proposed solution helped you or if you had some problem with the proposed steps. If it has fulfilled the problem solution then kindly accept the solution.

Comment: will you be more elaborate how to use or please provide samples

Comment: Thanks for responding, can you provide  the efforts you applied for understanding gson

Comment: Kindly let me know if the your concern has been resolved else kindly accept the answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpfull

```
public class FlatObject {

    private int parentId;
    private String techName;
    List<Technology> childList = new ArrayList<Technology>(1000);

    public FlatObject() {
        this.parentId = 1;
        this.techName = "Root";
        if(this.childList.isEmpty()){
            ((ArrayList<Technology>) this.childList).ensureCapacity(1000);
            this.childList.add(new Technology("Node 1",2,1));
            this.childList.add(new Technology("Node 1.1",3,2));
            this.childList.add(new Technology("Node 1.2",4,2));

            this.childList.add(new Technology("Node 2",5,1));
            this.childList.add(new Technology("Node 2.1",6,5));
            this.childList.add(new Technology("Node 2.2",7,5));
            this.childList.add(new Technology("Node 2.3",8,5));
        }
    }

public @ResponseBody List<FlatObject> getTechList() {
FlatObject ensureCapacity = new FlatObject();
        FlatObject ensureCapacity1 = new FlatObject();
        List<FlatObject> techList = new ArrayList<>();
        techList.add(ensureCapacity);
        techList.add(ensureCapacity1);
        return techList;
}

[
  {
    "techName": "Root",
    "parentId": 1,
    "childList": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parentid": 1,
        "techName": "Node 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "parentid": 2,
        "techName": "Node 1.1"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "parentid": 2,
        "techName": "Node 1.2"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "parentid": 1,
        "techName": "Node 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "parentid": 5,
        "techName": "Node 2.1"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "parentid": 5,
        "techName": "Node 2.2"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "parentid": 5,
        "techName": "Node 2.3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "techName": "Root",
    "parentId": 1,
    "childList": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parentid": 1,
        "techName": "Node 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "parentid": 2,
        "techName": "Node 1.1"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "parentid": 2,
        "techName": "Node 1.2"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "parentid": 1,
        "techName": "Node 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "parentid": 5,
        "techName": "Node 2.1"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "parentid": 5,
        "techName": "Node 2.2"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "parentid": 5,
        "techName": "Node 2.3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```